# Issue with displacement in 2.8 but working fine in 2.7 (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, versions

Why can't I get the same result I achieved when using blender 2.7?

### **2.7:**

[image: 2.7 Render]

[image: 2.7 Nodes]

### **2.8:**

[image: 2.8 Render]

[image: 2.8 Nodes]